# Use LocMemCache for selective Django pytest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pytest, pytest-django

I have a custom Throttling classes based on Django REST framework's [SimpleRateThrottle](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/throttling.py#L52) and I would like to test my custom class with pytest. Since my default test settings uses DummyCache, I would like to switch to LocMemCache for just this particular test module(SimpleRateThrottle uses cache backend to track counts). Is there a way to switch the cache backend for just selective tests? Setting settings.CACHE in a fixture doesn't seem to work. I also tried mocking the default_cache inside the SimpleRateThrottle, but I couldn't get it right.

## naive_throttler.py

```
from rest_framework.throttling import SimpleRateThrottle

class NaiveThrottler(SimpleRateThrottle):
   ...
```

## rest_framework/throttling.py

```
from django.core.cache import cache as default_cache  # Or how can I patch this?

class SimpleRateThrottle(BaseThrottle):
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django provides [`override_settings` and `modify_settings`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings) decorators for this. If you want to change the `CACHES` settings just for one test you can do this:

```
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings

class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    @override_settings(CACHES = {
                           'default': {
                              'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
                           }
                      })
    def test_chache(self):
        # your test code
```

Comment: This is great news, but it doesn't seem to support pytest does it?

Comment: I just used it with pytest on a normal function, should work with class functions too

Answer (score 3):

While the Django provided functions/decorators may work, `pytest-django` provides a [fixture for changing settings for a test](http://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#settings). To better follow `pytest`'s paradigm of [using fixtures for tests](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture), it would be best to change the settings specific to a test as follows:

```
import pytest

def test_cache(settings):
    settings.CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
        }
    }
    # test logic here
```

Comment: you saved my day!

Comment: Ah, thanks! Note to anyone else who makes a dumb mistake like I did - this does not throw an error, but it also does not work! : `settings.CACHES['default']['BACKEND'] = 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache'`